# When I add data to datagrid in XAML doesn't update

Tags: wpf, vb.net, xaml, datagrid

I cannot get my `DataGrid` to populate with data. I'm new to XAML. I'm using an `OracleDataReader` object and would like to add it to the `DataGrid`. First here is the XAML:

```
<DataGrid Name="grdResults" FontSize="25" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserResizeRows="False" DockPanel.Dock="Top" IsReadOnly="True">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=extName}" Header="Name"  Width="*" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=location_note}"  Header="Location" Width="*" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=crate_no}" Header="Crate" Width="*"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

And here is the behind the scenes. Seems Like it should work but it is not. The fields are named the same as they are bound in the XAML. RS is a populated `OracleDataReader`.

```
Dim dt As New DataTable
dt.Load(rs)
grdResults.DataContext = dt.DefaultView
```

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

**EDIT :**

I was able to get it to work. Probably not the best way but works for me. I took out the datagrid.columns and childs from the XAML and put this in the behind the scenes between dt.Load(rs) And setting the datacontext

```
    grdResults.Columns.Add(New DataGridTextColumn() With { _
        .Header = "Name", _
        .Binding = New Binding(String.Format("[{0}]", "extName"))})

    grdResults.Columns.Add(New DataGridTextColumn() With { _
        .Header = "Location", _
        .Binding = New Binding(String.Format("[{0}]", "location_note"))})

    grdResults.Columns.Add(New DataGridTextColumn() With { _
        .Header = "Crate", _
        .Binding = New Binding(String.Format("[{0}]", "crate_no"))})
```

Comment: I fully discourage the use of `System.Data` classes in WPF client-side. Create a proper data model to hold your data and proper ViewModels to define the application logic.

Comment: But if I had that would it be possible to display it in a grid?

Comment: of course dude. WPF is much more capable than winforms. I don't understand your question.

Comment: Did you try it with AutoGenerateColumns = True?

Comment: Yes but there are some rows that I do not want to use.

Comment: You need to use some sort of an ObservableCollection or a collection that raises NotifyOnPropertyChange.
I strongly recommend going to a ModelView/View/Model for better isolation and binding simplicity.

Comment: Its such a headache for me trying to wrap my head around the MVVM stuff. And my company has been doing winforms so long it just seems hard to adapt it. Especially without any formal training and just reading on the internet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, you did right for `AutoGeneratedColumn = false`
If you want to skip some columns of the database, you can just firstly hide all of them by setting 

`Columns.Item(x).Visibility = Windows.Visibility.Hidden` and then show only selected ones.

To skip rows you can just remove them from the `DataView` (it is better to create separate `DataView` for viewing, if you want to do that, and provide custom data collection method)

Another (better) way of disabling separate row is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11107434/disabled-row-on-datagrid-wpf-getting-selected-when-clicked-with-the-right-mouse?rq=1)